# React router Link not working in production

Tags: reactjs, dockerfile, react-router-dom

I am facing an issue with `react-router` v6.12.1, when running my application in production.
When I click on a `Link` or use the `navigate()` function it doesn't work but the url path changes.
When I refresh the page, I am redirected to the view of the url as expected.
Here is my routing configuration:

```
export const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <RootPage/>
    },
    {
        path: '/dashboard',
        element: <Guard
                fallback={<DashboardAppShellSkeleton/>}
                uri={'/dashboard/groups'}
                unwantedRoles={['GYM']}><DashboardAppShellComponent/></Guard>,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'memberships',
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<CustomerMembershipsSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/dashboard'} unwantedRoles={['GYM']}><MyMembershipsPage/></Guard>,
                },
                {
                    path: 'bookings',
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<CustomerMembershipsSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/dashboard'} unwantedRoles={['GYM']}><CustomerBookingsPage/></Guard>,
                },
                {
                    path: 'groups',
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<CustomerGroupsSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/dashboard'} unwantedRoles={['GYM']}><CustomerGroupsPage/></Guard>,
                },
                {
                    path: 'groups/:groupId',
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<CustomerSelectedGroupSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/dashboard'}
                        unwantedRoles={['GYM']}><CustomerSelectedGroupPage/></Guard>,
                },
                {
                    path: "my-profile",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<CustomerMyProfileSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/dashboard/my-profile'}
                        unwantedRoles={['GYM']}><CustomerMyProfilePage/></Guard>
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            path: '/admin',
            element: <Guard
                fallback={<AdminAppShellSkeleton/>}
                uri={'/admin/members'}
                wantedRoles={['GYM']}><AdminAppShellComponent/></Guard>,
            children: [
                {
                    path: "home",
                    element: <Guard uri={'/admin/home'} wantedRoles={['GYM']}><HomePage/></Guard>
                },
                {
                    path: "members",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<MembersSkeletonPage/>}
                        uri={'/admin/members'}
                        wantedRoles={['GYM']}
                    ><MembersPage/></Guard>,
                },
                {
                    path: "members/:memberId",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<SelectedMemberSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/admin/members'}
                        wantedRoles={['GYM']}
                    ><SelectedMemberPage/></Guard>
                },
                {
                    path: "memberships",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<MembershipsSkeletonPage/>}
                        uri={'/admin/memberships'}
                        wantedRoles={['GYM']}
                    ><MembershipsPage/></Guard>
                },
                {
                    path: "memberships/:templateId",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<SelectedMembershipSkeletonPage/>}
                        uri={'/admin/memberships'}
                        wantedRoles={['GYM']}
                    ><SelectedMembershipPage/></Guard>
                },
                {
                    path: "classes",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<ClassesSkeletonPage/>}
                        uri={'/admin/classes'}
                        wantedRoles={['GYM']}
                    ><ClassesPage/></Guard>,
                },
                {
                    path: "classes/:classId",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<SelectedClassSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/admin/classes'}
                        wantedRoles={['GYM']}
                    ><SelectedClassPage/></Guard>
                },
                {
                    path: "classes/:classId/groups/:groupId",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<SelectedGroupSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/admin/classes'}
                        wantedRoles={['GYM']}
                    ><SelectedGroupPage/></Guard>
                },
                {
                    path: "my-profile",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<MyProfileSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/admin/my-profile'}
                        wantedRoles={['GYM']}><MyProfilePage/></Guard>
                },
                {
                    path: "statistics",
                    element: <Guard
                        fallback={<StatisticsSkeleton/>}
                        uri={'/admin/my-profile'}
                        wantedRoles={['GYM']}><StatisticsPage/></Guard>
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            path: '/check-in-screen',
            element: <Guard
                fallback={<CheckInScreenSkeleton/>}
                uri={'/admin/members'}
                wantedRoles={['GYM']}
            ><CheckInScreenPage/></Guard>,
        },
        {
            path: '/terms-conditions',
            element: <Suspense fallback={<AdminAppShellSkeleton/>}><TermsConditionsPage/></Suspense>,
        },
        {
            path: '/gym-terms',
            element: <Suspense fallback={<AdminAppShellSkeleton/>}><GymTermsPage/></Suspense>,
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            element: <Suspense fallback={<AdminAppShellSkeleton/>}><NotFoundPage/></Suspense>,
        }
    ]
)
```

and my initialization of react router

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { ProvidersComponent } from "./features/admin/layout";
import KeycloakService from "./common/utils/auth/keycloak";
import { RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import { router } from "./app.routing";
import HttpService from "./common/utils/rest/HttpService";
import TranslationService from "./i18n";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

const renderApp = () => root.render(
    <ProvidersComponent>
        <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    </ProvidersComponent>
);
KeycloakService.initKeycloak(renderApp);
TranslationService.initTranslations(renderApp)
HttpService.configure();
```

I am running production in a docker container where I build its image with this Dockerfile:

```
# Use the latest LTS version of Node.js as the base image
FROM node:18.15.0 as builder

# Set the working directory to /app inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy app files
COPY . .

# Install dependencies (yarn.lock ensures the exact versions of dependencies are installed)
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

# Build the app
RUN yarn run build

# Bundle static assets with nginx
FROM nginx:1.21.0 as production

# Set the environment variable
ENV NODE_ENV local

# Copy built assets from `builder` image
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Add your nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Expose port
EXPOSE 80

# Start nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I my local environment I don't face this issue since I don't use the built image.
Do you know what may cause this issue?

Comment: This looks to be a known, reported [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10579) with RRDv6.12.0/6.12.1. For now it seems that rolling back to v6.12.0 or even back to v.6.11.x doesn't have this production build issue.

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks!

Comment: It seems that this issue is getting asked about a lot as of late, so I would like to leave an answer that you can hopefully upvote or accept so to provide a duplicate target for the other questions.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to be a known, reported [issue](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10579) with `react-router` v6.12.0/6.12.1.

[[Bug]: v6.12.1 Navigating and changing pages does not work. No errors in console #10579](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10579#issuecomment-1587665443)

> Hey folks - it looks like throughout this thread there are two
> separate issues being discussed:
>
> 1. **`6.12.1`-only Production Mode Issue**
>
>    `6.12.0` works correctly, but `6.12.1` doesn't perform navigations in production mode (works correctly in dev mode). This is due to a
>    `webpack/terser` minification issue introduced in #10569 and resolved
>    by #10588 and currently available in `6.12.2-pre.0`. If this is what
>    your are seeing in your application, please give `6.12.2-pre.0` a shot
>    and add a  reaction to this comment to let us know that the
>    prerelease resolves your issue. If you still have issues with the
>    prerelease, please respond with a comment and ideally a minimal
>    reproduction.
> 2. **startTransition-enabled Navigation Issues**
>
>    `6.12.0` and `6.12.1` don't work correctly in your app when your navigations leverage `Suspense` internally, likely due to the
>    recreation of net-new promises during renders. This is shown by the
>    codesandbox in this comment and further here and the few comments
>    following. If this is your issue we're still diving into this and hope
>    to have an update for you shortly.
>
> Apologies for the inconvenience and thanks for bearing with us!

For now it seems that rolling back to v6.12.0 or even back to v.6.11.x doesn't have this production build issue.

There appears to be a [fix in the works for a 6.13 release](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/10579#issuecomment-1589858428).