# Page not refreshing with URL change in Production Mode for react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I tried updating `react-router-dom` from `6.3.0` to `6.12.1`. Given the fact that the major number hadn't changed I was hoping it would be backwards compatible and for the most part it is, everything continued working normally -- *except* when I do a production build, at which point clicking links (e.g. in the app's header) doesn't work; the URL changes in the address bar but the page doesn't change.

In dev mode everything works as expected. I even have cases where I'm using params to pass information to some components, and it all works. When I do a production build, however, the UI doesn't react to changes. When I click links the URL in the address bar changes but the UI doesn't. (Hitting **Refresh** with the new URL *does* cause the screen to change as expected.)

As mentioned, I can force it to work by clicking **Refresh**:

1. I click a link (even one with a param attached to it
2. The address in the address bar changes but the screen doesn't
3. I hit **Refresh** and the page loads as expected

I also tried following the [tutorial](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial) and using the `createBrowserRouter()` function, but I get the same result.

For reference, here are some highlights of the app:

`Index.tsx` is pretty standard other than including Redux and Redux Persist:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

`App.tsx` is, I *think,* using standard r-r-d components:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Header } from './common/Header';
import { Home } from './home/Home';
const Do = lazy(() => import('./do/Do'));
const SizeIndicator = lazy(() => import('./common/SizeIndicator'));
const FourOhFour = lazy(() => import('./common/FourOhFour'));

export const App = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Suspense fallback="...">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Header />
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/do" element={<Do />} />
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="*" element={<FourOhFour />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
        <SizeIndicator />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And I won't show the whole header but it uses `NavLink` components similar to this:

```
import { NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

return <div>
  <NavLink key="/" className="nav-link" to="/" end>Home</NavLink>
  <NavLink key="/do" className="nav-link" to="/do" end>Do</NavLink>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76466318/react-router-link-not-working-in-production Try reverting to `react-router-dom@6.12.0` exactly, and if the issue persists, back to `react-router-dom@6.11`.

Comment: Thanks for this, Drew! I missed that question in my search, but reverting to `6.12.0` did solve the problem for me.

Comment: No worries, it *was* asked only about an hour prior to yours, but there was also a question yesterday or the day before that was effectively the same issue. On that note, in the github issue thread it looks like 6.12.2 may have a fix for it.