# React-router-dom bugs when I use lazy load and only changes the route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, lazy-loading

I'm trying to use lazy loading to improve the loading time of my website. In development everything runs normally, but when I build the project it stops working. I click on a link, the route changes, but the website just doesn't loads the new components and it only works after pressing f5.

It was working normally and now it suddenly stopped.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer';
import Loading from './components/Loading/Loading';
import ScrollToTop from './components/ScrollToTop/ScrollToTop';

const Home = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/Home/Home'));
const Projects = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/Projects/Projects'));
const AboutUs = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/AboutUs/AboutUs'));
const Contact = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/Contact/Contact'));
const Invest = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/Invest/Invest'));
const NotFound = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/NotFound/NotFound'));

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={
            <React.Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
              <Home />
            </React.Suspense>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="projects"
          element={ 
            <React.Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
              <Projects />
            </React.Suspense>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/aboutus"
          element={ 
            <React.Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
              <AboutUs />
            </React.Suspense>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/contact"
          element={ 
            <React.Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
              <Contact />
            </React.Suspense>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="/invest"
          element={ 
            <React.Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
              <Invest />
            </React.Suspense>
          }
        />
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={ 
            <React.Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
              <NotFound />
            </React.Suspense>
          }
        />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What version of `react-router-dom` are you using? Sounds like your issue could be resolved using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76475101/8690857).

Comment: Drew, I updated and it started working again thanks for the help